# How to manually control exposure duration with AVFoundation in OSX?

Tags: macos, avfoundation, avcapturedevice, avcapture

I'm using AVFoundation to capture images from a connected camera. I need to be able to control the exposure manually, instead of it being automatic.

I've found AVCaptureDevice.exposureMode (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1388858-exposuremode) which allows me to set the mode to locked or custom, but then the associated iso and exposureDuration properties are iOS only.

Is there any way to control exposure duration in AVFoundation in OSX? Or even with another framework?